# Angular using a service variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have injected a service into a directive, is there a way that I can share the data in the service in the directive

like if I have some directive called `resultsDirective`, some service called `dataService` has been injected (making these up as I go along). Is there a way that I can access a variable from the service in the directive? for the sake of some implementation:

```
angular.module("someModule").service("dataService", function() {
    var shareVariable;
})

angular.module("someModule").directive("resultsDirective" , ["dataService", function(dataService) {
    return {
        restrict: ,
        scope: ,
        link: function() {}

        //sorry about the lack of implementation here, just made something skeletal
    }
}])
```

so if I just wanted to `console.log` the `shareVariable` in the `resultsDirective`, how would I access that data? I am sure in Angular there is an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an angular issue, this is a javascript issue. You can't access locally scoped variables outside the scope. You would have to expose the sharedVariable by doing something like this

```
angular.module("someModule").service("dataService", function() {
    this.shareVariable = null;
});


(function () {

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.service("dataService", function () {
        this.shareVariable = 'shohel';
    });

    app.directive("resultsDirective", ["dataService", function (dataService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope, ele, att) {
                var svc = dataService.shareVariable;
            }
        };

    }]);
})();
```

Comment: you are not returning nothing for the service https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services

Comment: @donnanicolas that's using a factory. He's using a service. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#service

Answer (score 0):

First, remember services are kind of singletons, so modifying a variable inside a service will have effect in all of your application. The issue your are having is that you don't know what closure is, I recommend take a look into that [JS Closure](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FGuide%2FClosures&ei=Ri0PVP-bLdGXgwS4poLQAw&usg=AFQjCNE6OynGW23ihLHMWBBBjzvUzUK9SQ&sig2=4RPlx_CHDZOF4_EfCTWS_A&bvm=bv.74649129,d.eXY)

How to solve this? Two options:

- Return an object with the property (not recommended, can get messy)
- Make a getter/setter functionality

Code example

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule' []);
myModule.factoy('service', function () {
    var myVariable;

    return {
        getMyVariable: function () { return myVariable; },
        setMyVariable: function (newVal) { myVariable = newVal; }
    }
});
```

There is actually much more you can do, but I don't know what you need

Also your service won't work, take a look at: [Creating Services - AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services)